# jquery ajax json Array to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, json

Friends I dont know is it possible or not, But want to do like mentioned as below, if possible give me the best solution..

index.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydb') or die (mysql_error());
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            success : function(data){
              alert(data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Submit">
    <?php print_r($_REQUEST['data'])?>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydb') or die (mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query('select * from user');
$count = count($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $data['name'][] = $row['name'];
}
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

When I click on submit ajax will call and will get response from in json encoded string as below

```
{"name":["Nakul Kabra","Bridget Louise","Jayesh Joshi","Jignesh Chaudhary","Jitendra Vihol","Spec Develop","Harshad Sadclown","Andy Estep","Rohan"]}
```

Now i want to store this ajax response in PHP variable and display it.
How to solve this problem, can anybody help me please..??

Thanks, In advance !!
Your regards.

Comment: When you receive the response you will be on the client side where you can't run PHP. You are using javascript on the client side.

Comment: Where do you want to use the variable again once you have set it?

Comment: Yes You are Right, But still is there any way or any how can we make it possible to store that json array in php Array.. Do you have any idea, or logic..???

Comment: i want to display that names as a list in a table and after that i want to make edit functionality on each name..

Comment: I would use jQuery to insert it into a form so that they can edit, then when the form is submitted you can work with it in PHP on the server side.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible. You already had the data in a PHP array before you sent it to the client side. Once the json array arrives, it's not possible to store it in as a PHP array. That would of course require sending it back to the server.

In your AJAX success function, you can parse the json and insert it into a form (or any other HTML element). Here's an example:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj.name, function(index, value) {
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'name[]',
        value: value
    }).appendTo('#name_box');
});
```

Here's a sample form:

```
<form action="edit_names.php" method="post">
    <div id="name_box"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so Much **@Pé de Leão**... Its being helpful to me..
Thanks a lot man !!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like to are trying to persist data across page requests. Remember each page request, be it a page refresh or an ajax request, creates a new php runtime. Variables are not stored across these, but there are of course multiple techniques used to allow this behaviour to occur. The most common way to persist data across page requests is to use PHP sessions and cookies.

This is a useful [article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/working-with-sessions-and-cookies-in-php-and-mysql/) which explains in a nice amount of detail how to implement sessions and cookies.